# Generate Binary Data Array From a Range of Numbers

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, binary

I need to create Boolean/Binary arrays with rows representing the binary form of each number in given a range. Each column hold values for a given bit position. The range is determined by the bit-width and binary encoding scheme. Then I need to count the number of cells in a column that do not match the preceding cell.

I believe the counting process is simply XORing the array with itself shifted down one row. The sum of each column in the XOR result is my transition count.

I need to do this for each combination of [signed, unsigned] values encoded as [hexadecimal, octal, decimal]. Mismatches between the encoding scheme and available bits results in unusable bits.
 *e.g. A 4-bit unsigned octal array would still only have 8 rows. However, if it is signed then that 4th bit is used for sign and the array is the full 16 rows.*

The ultimate goal is to create labeled set of summary n-grams for the number of transitions at each bit position for various bit widths, encoding, and use of sign. The summary n-gram for example 1 would be {3-bit, octal, unsigned, [1, 3, 7]}. The summary n-gram for example 3 is {4-bit, octal, signed, [1, 2, 6, 13]}. Example 4 is {4-bit, hexadecimal, signed, [1, 2, 6, 13]}.

**Examples:**
**1)** 8x3 Binary array of all possible 3-bit unsigned octal values:
0   0   0
0   0   1
0   1   0
0   1   1
1   0   0
1   0   1
1   1   0
1   1   1

**2)** 8x4 Binary array of all possible 4-bit unsigned octal values:
Same as #1 except with an additional leftmost column of all zeros

**3)** 16x4 Binary array of all possible 4-bit signed octal values:
Note: It's ok to double count zero (-0 and +0)
1   1   1   1
1   1   1   0
1   1   0   1
1   1   0   0
1   0   1   1
1   0   1   0
1   0   0   1
1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1
0   0   1   0
0   0   1   1
0   1   0   0
0   1   0   1
0   1   1   0
0   1   1   1

**4)** 16x4 Binary array of all possible 4-bit signed hexadecimal values:
Same as #3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.unpackbits`, for example

```
np.unpackbits(np.arange(8).astype(np.uint8)[:, None], axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Slice off unwanted zeros:

```
np.unpackbits(np.arange(8).astype(np.uint8)[:, None], axis = 1)[:, -3:]
```

Result:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Use modulo for signed values:

```
np.unpackbits((np.arange(-4, 4)%8).astype(np.uint8)[:, None], axis = 1)[:, -3:]
```

Or view casting from signed to unsigned:

```
np.unpackbits(np.arange(-4, 4).astype(np.int8).view(np.uint8)[:, None], axis = 1)[:, -3:]
```

Result:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Transition count:

```
x = np.unpackbits(np.arange(-4, 4).astype(np.int8).view(np.uint8)[:, None], axis = 1)[:, -3:]
np.abs(np.diff(x.view(np.int8), axis=0)).sum(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
array([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1])
```

Or using your xor method:

```
(x[1:]^x[:-1]).sum(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
array([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1], dtype=uint64)
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about unpack bits.